# the set G = {1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 12}.

Tags: abstract-algebra

i)Is G isomorphic to Z(interger)6? Justify your answer.

ii)State Cayley’s theorem and find a subgroup in S6 which is isomorphic to G.

Not quite sure what to do here.

Comment: Hi, could you explain the operation of the "group" $G$?

Comment: Closed under the binary operation x,y>xy(mod13) hope this helps.

Comment: You should state the operation of the group in your question otherwise it lacks of context. Try to make a good question giving definitions and your thoughts, otherwise you will just get downvotes. Also, try to use Latex https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the set $G$ is a group under multiplication modulo $13$ as Learner40 stated in his comment.

Now, observe that $4^2 \equiv \;3\; \text{mod}\; 13$, so $$4^6\equiv \;4^3 \cdot 4^3\equiv 12 \cdot 12 \equiv 144 \equiv 1 \; \text{mod}\;13$$ so order of $4$ is six, so $G$ is cyclic and hence $G \simeq \Bbb Z_6$

The other part is easy!